# What is the simplest method of displaying a GeometryModel3D as a point cloud? (HelixToolkit / SharpDX / DirectX)

Tags: graphics, directx-11, direct3d, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using **HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX** to display a mesh in the 3D viewport. A requirement I have is to display any given mesh as solid, wireframe and point cloud.

The solid and wireframe implementation is simple, since the **GeometryModel3D** object provides the **FillMode** property in order to switch between them.

However I cannot find a simple way to switch the display to a point cloud. What I mean by this is that each vertex should display a small point. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I need the switching of the display to occur very quickly, just as switching between solid and wireframe is extremely quick.

Example images below:

[image: Solid]

[image: Wireframe]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot simply toggle between Mesh and Point representation. You have to transform your mesh model to a PointGeometryModel3D and use its Point collection to visualize.

Comment: Thank you - that is what I have used, it works well with good performance.